# Null is not an object (evaluating 'ImageCropPicker.openPicker')

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-crop-picker

I am using this package: https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker.
I followed all the installation steps for android.
But as soon as I import

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
```

into my file, I receive the error saying:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ImageCropPicker.openPicker')
```

Anyone else experience this?
What would the solution be?

Comment: Did you try this https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1762?

Comment: You need to reinstall the application in android and delete the cache data. it will work for me.

Comment: @VuPhung yep ive tried that but no luck :(